# I tried to link TextBox to my Rod class, but changing the TextBox.Text will not change the Rod fields. Whats wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am dynamically creating rows using a Grid, which is a nested GroupBox, which has these custom TextBoxes. I bind it to my Rod class, but tried to change the fields of the TextBox.Text does not change the fields of Rod

```
    public RodTextBox(string text,string propertyName, Rod rod)
    {
        Text = text;
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        addBinding(propertyName ,rod);
    }
    public void addBinding(string propertyName, Rod rod )
    {
        Binding myBinding = new Binding($"{propertyName}");
        myBinding.Source = rod;
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
    }
   
 }
```

Comment: `($"{propertyName}")` returns the same value as `(propertyName)`. formatted string is totally redundant

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your definition of Rod, and of course your call to RodTextBox.

Just guessing though, maybe the property in Rod you are binding to doesn't have {get; set;}?

In Visual Studio, you can also enable WPF binding errors (tools->options->Debugging->WPF Trace Settings->DataBinding to All) and see if the console shows any binding errors.